# Adding Tab dynamically

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I have a tab and want another tab with click of button.
Another tab has VBox (Contains charts,grid etc).
It gives an error while adding code addChild(), removeChild() on button click.
The error is of null object reference.

Please suggest me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're probably trying to access children of a tab that has not been initialized yet.  The simplest solution is to change the creationPolicy property of your TabNavigator to "all".

You can see an [explanation of creationPolicy](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=layoutperformance_05.html) in the Adobe documentation.

If this is not the solution, you're probably going to have to post more specific code.